# How to save an image without antialiasing in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, antialiasing

I think this question has been raised numerous of times, but I have yet not found an answer that works.

I'm rendering game graphics with cycles and I need them to be saved in RGB, without any alpha information what so ever.

Setup:

[image] [image]

I want to save this picture, exactly as it appears here, with no alpha. But it always saves an antialiased version of it against black.

How can I save the image without antialiased result?

Comment: could you add two small images with how the result looks right now and exactly how you want it to look?

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think the antialiasing is stored as alpha values in a single layer `PNG`, rather just a mix of whatever color and black (in RGB colors). So with the settings you have now, there is no alpha information being saved.

Comment: @Gandalf3 I need the object to not be antialised against the background, but still within the object itself. So far Peter's solution worked best for me.

Comment: @MaxKielland I agree PeterT's solution is better, but my solution should work for doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you still want AA within the image, just not at the borders, so I'd suggest that you render with a transparent background and remove the border AA in the compositor:

[image: Nodes]

There's obviously ugly aliasing artifacts here but you could fine-tune the "Greater Than" Node or process multiple alpha ranges differently.

Comment: I went for this solution. It was independent of the objects and I see how it works, I can fine tune it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any advantage to using **Image** > *Separate RGBA* > **Alpha** instead of using the **Alpha** socket of the *RenderLayers* node?

Comment: @WChargin nope, I just threw this together, you obviously don't need the RGB node either, since you can set the color on the empty image slot on the Mix node itself

Comment: To make the background transparent, connect "Greather Than" output to "Composite" Alpha socket. Also, "Set Alpha" node is not required.

Answer (score 15):

In 2.67 and 2.68a (I haven't checked 2.69+), the amount of AA present in the cycles render is controlled by the size of the Gaussian sample on the film.

The gaussian for the film is the amount of jitter that rays leaving the camera receive. If this is high, the pixel effectively samples a little circle of incoming light in the scene, and you get anti-aliasing. If this is small, then all the rays are almost the same, and you are sampling one single point on the film.

So to reduce or remove anti-aliasing in Cycles, turn down the Gaussian width in the Film section of the Render settings. Turning it to 0 will reset it to its minimum (currently 0.01 on my version, the default is 1.50), and rendering will give essentially a non AA image.

[image]

If you just want to avoid an aliased outline, then this isn't the right setting, do it in the compositor as per PeterT's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The *Anti-Aliasing* option does nothing for the Cycles renderer, it's only for the OpenGL renderer (=viewport render).

If you wanna have a Cycles render with no AA, try this:

1. *Sampling* panel, set from *Path Tracing* to *Branched Path Tracing*
2. Set *AA Samples* to 1
3. In the *Film* panel, untick *Transparent*
4. Save in RGB mode

Comment: Note that GPU does not work with the non-progressive integrator (it does in the RC, but the OP's screen-shot is of an older version)

Comment: It sort of worked in 2.69 RC1, but it could occasionally crash on Windows (which is really a Windows problem, stupid timeout error whereby OS believes the GPU crashed if it doesn't respond fast enough and resets driver).

Comment: Is this for Blender 2.69RC? I on 2.68.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to remove anti-aliasing in cycles is with *composite nodes* and [*ID Masks*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor#ID_Mask_Node):

1. Enable *Object Index* in *Renderlayers > Passes*:

   [image]
2. Set the *pass index*  of all the objects to `1` by

   1. <kbd>A</kbd>*> Select all* (to ensure you have all objects selected, you may also need to un-hide hidden objects (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) and toggle all layers visible (<kbd>~</kbd>))
   2. Set *Object Data > Relations > Pass Index* to `1`
   3. Right click on the *Pass index* setting, and select *Copy to selected*:

      [image]
3. This will add a new output to the *Renderlayer* node. By plugging it into an *Id Mask* node and setting the *Index* to `1`, you can generate a mask of all the objects. This mask will not be antialiased when the *Anti-Aliasing* option is disabled:

   [image]
4. Use the resulting aliased mask as a *Mix factor* to remove anti-aliasing from the render. This will only remove anti-aliasing from the edges next to the sky, leaving the edges over other objects smooth:

   [image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just as a side-note, if there's not transparent surfaces this gives almost the same results as filtering for alpha>0.5 meaning that it will still contain some pixels mixed with the background color if cycles is set to use AA, but they're fairly unnoticeable compared to what the default output gives you.

Comment: @PeterT Your solution is better, +1 :)

Comment: objectively it can go both ways, with your method you don't get [these artifacts](http://i.imgur.com/0pU0FWR.png) on straight lines. But using "Greater Than" values of 0.85 seems to be a good compromise.

Comment: I did tried this one too, but at a first glance Peter's solution seemed to give me more control and I don't have to fiddle with the index for each object. Thank you any way..

Comment: @MaxKielland PeterT's answer is the better one, but I have updated this answer anyway. (you shouldn't have to fiddle with the the pass index for individual objects, so I tried to clarify)

Comment: I did try out your solution and it works probably perfectly all right in some applications, but for me I got a one pixel dark rim and no way of adjustments.

Comment: @MaxKielland Odd.. and *Anti-aliasing* was disabled on the *ID Mask* node?

Comment: Yes, it was. As I said it doesn't do the full trick for my specific application. I have a lot of lines in 26 degree angels... I'm sure it works perfectly well in other situations.