# how do I create a sprite with hard (aliased) edges, but still be antialiased inside?

Tags: rendering, image

This question came up in the irc channel yesterday.  The fellow had a model he was turning into a sprite for a 2D game.  He wanted it to be aliased inside, but have a hard (aliased) edge.

Getting transparent images is easy.  Go to the Render Properties panel and set your Alpha to Transparent and make sure the file format is saving RGBA channels.

[image]

Getting a hard (aliased) edge is easy.  Turn off Anti-Aliasing in the Render Properties.  This gives your model hard edges, even in the internal pixels.

[image: turn off Anti-Aliasing in the Render Properties]

Now if turn on anti-aliasing you get soft edges, both inside, and outside.

[image: turn on Anti-Aliasing in the Render Properties]

How do you get hard edges on the outside, but soft edges inside?

Comment: Related: [How to save an image without antialiasing in cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3299/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 Where is the anti-aliasing option in Blender 3? I am trying to render an emission object in front of a transparent background and I get black/grey pixels on the edge... :(

Comment: @MicroMachine This question about the old Blender Internal engine which is no longer in blender, for modern blender the closest setting is this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3554/599 (though its not perfect). For getting aliasing on top of a transparent background, this composite node setup should be applicable: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3301/599

Comment: @gandalf3 I did [this](https://imgur.com/s7IMsuC) and I got [this](https://imgur.com/1ya82Ac) problem is still there

Comment: @MicroMachine Ah yeah, it isn't perfect and the higher the samples the more it gets smoothed. The [scrambling distance multiplier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) can also help, though it is also not perfect and may introduce other unwanted effects. Instead [you could perhaps try the node setup in the accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3301/599)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer was composed based on help from several individuals in the #blender IRC channel (you know who you are).

The first step is to use blender's Compositor.  Start out by clicking the Use Nodes checkbox.  That should create the two-node pipeline that does nothing exciting.  Route the alpha channel through Math node (available through the Converter submenu of the shift-A menu) configured to do a Greater Than operation against 0.001.  This means that an alpha of 0 will remain zero, but an alpha of 0.001 or higher (and 0.001 < 1/255)  will be converted to 1.

[image: Compositor with Greater Than applied to alpha channel]

The problem that remains is that the edges that otherwise would have been translucent are now kind of dark.  That's because the Image channel coming out of the Render Layers node is premultiplied.  To correct for this, add an Alpha Convert node (available under the Converter submenu) and route the image channel through that on its way to the Composite node.

[image: Compositor with Alpha Convert from premultiplied to straight]

Now your edges are hard and they match the thresholded alpha channel.