# How do I anti-alias an image with a transparent background without getting semi transparent pixels?

Tags: rendering, transparency, antialiasing

This question has already been asked and answered here:

[how do I create a sprite with hard (aliased) edges, but still be antialiased inside?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/how-do-i-create-a-sprite-with-hard-aliased-edges-but-still-be-antialiased-ins)

But this does not work for me. I think something has been left out.

I would have simply commented on that question, but I need 50 reputation.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: Add a screenshot, or provide a blend-file

Comment: I figured it out. Under Anti-Aliasing, Full Sample needs to be unchecked. What was happening was my renders were exactly the same with or without that node setup in the link.

Comment: @JayRockets Please write an answer to your own question. Other users facing the same issue will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Full Sample. This needs to be left unchecked.

[image]