# Object Specific Anti-Aliasing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, antialiasing

I have one object in my scene that I need rendered without any Anti-Aliasing, but I'd like the rest of the scene to still be Anti-Aliased, is there any way to achieve this? I'm using Cycles.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/how-to-save-an-image-without-antialiasing-in-cycles

Comment: I already know how to disable anti-aliasing in Cycles thanks mate.

Comment: It's quite unusual that you would want different AA levels throughout the scene.

Comment: @vader It's an interesting set of circumstances.

Comment: You could try rendering the object at very low resolution against a black or transparent background before compositing it into the main scene.  The low res image component that is being scaled up will have exaggerated aliasing compared to everything else.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Well the goal is to not have any anti-aliasing, your comment says it would have exaggerated aliasing...And sadly, the object has textures on it, so that would kill them.

Answer (score 3):

Blender/Cycles doesn't have this feature currently

Comment: Couldn't it be done using multiple linked scenes?

Comment: Only if you render in different layers and composite after.

Also, cycles cant render without AA, currently.

Comment: Actually if you turn the width (under film) down to 0.01 it will all but remove AA. But sadly, not completely.