# How do I get my renders to not antialias with the background? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, transparency, antialiasing

I'm currently working on a project that requires 2d-rendered sprites however I need for the sprites to have aliased borders/outlines with the background while the rest of the image is antialiased. I am using Cycles so I think the only way I can do this is through compositing.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/how-to-save-an-image-without-antialiasing-in-cycles

Comment: Paul I looked at that post, but I still want my background to be transparent, not opaque.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? See my attached screenshot. Rendered in cycles.
It is a very easy compositing node tree.

Is this what you expect? Antialiasing inside objects, but aliasing outside. Works with transparent background only.

Best wishes
Chris

[image]