# How to get pixelated edges look? (PS1, DS, etc.)

Tags: rendering

I've been making low poly models but I'd like them to have the "pixelated" look that models have in some (mainly)older games. This especially includes PS1 games and 3D DS games. I'm not talking about the textures, but the way the overall thing is pixelated/no smooth edges. It seems to be the way the overall graphics were rendered. It's often more apparent when things are moving, but you can still see it in pictures too. Here's a few examples:

[The pillar and bookcases here](http://www.psypokes.com/bw/walkthrough/scientist.png)

[Just look at the character](https://i.gyazo.com/fb8d4d8365d3c6432efffd9c92131c9c.png)

[This model uses pixel art textures, and pixelated edges compliment the look so well](https://i.gyazo.com/92856e38e69698f5ba72766df67907c9.png)

I don't know how to best get this look but I'd really love to know, it'd help me a lot.

Comment: Hello, check out this post. It is old but perhaps it is still viable. It is the antialiasing you will have to remove. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/how-to-save-an-image-without-antialiasing-in-cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now tried the solution from the post regarding the filter width, and it works in 2.79 as well. You need to change the "filter type" value under "film" in the "render tab" to a low value. Please note that this will only be visible in the final render.

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thanks! On a side note for anyone looking for a similar effect: I also found it helps if you combine this method with making the resolution of the render lower.