# Old Game Texture Style Question

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine

I have a very basic question, honestly just the name/definition would help, about the way old games did their textures/graphics. I have this picture from a game called Mother. I'm wondering what the name is of the circled edges is called. In old games, the more diagonal an edge was to the players perspective, the more pixelated the line was. As you turned to look at it more dead on, it would become one flat edge. What is this called and can it be done it blender or is this accomplished more in the game engine you are working in? Is it based on low res textures or the object mesh or shading? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been racking my brain trying to remember what this is called. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The word you are looking for is _Aliasing_. Edges that become jagged based on angle are referred to as _aliased_. You don't see as much of it these days because much work has gone into _Anti-Aliasing_ technology (as it is generally considered undesirable). I think the closest you can come to re-introducing aliasing in blender is to go to _Preferences_ > _Viewport_ > _Quality_ and turn it off. This may only affect the viewport and not renders, though.

Comment: Also, if you are using Cycles, you can go to the _Film_ section of the _Render Properties_ tab and turn the _Pixel Filter_ down as low as it can go (0.01 I think - Gaussian may also work as the best type).

Comment: "To reduce or remove anti-aliasing in Cycles, turn down the Gaussian width in the Film section of the Render settings." (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3554/61453)

Answer (score 1):

This is called stair-stepping, or the staircase effect.  It's the lack of anti-aliasing causing this effect.

Comment: Thank you everyone who has replied that really helped a lot. One more question; if I wanted to have aliased edges like this on purpose in a game to replicate old graphics, is that something I would do in engine? (Using unreal if it helps)

Comment: I believe so, it's part of their post-processing pipeline.  Docs say it can be disabled - https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/PostProcessEffects/AntiAliasing/index.html